# I throw own error with text, but my API returns 500 error to client without description (I need it)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponse

I created an ASP.NET Core Web API. I throw own error with some text and try to get this text in my client. When I do it locally, it works. But when I hosted it in Azure, it does not work - I just get a 500 error.

This is in my controller:

```
 catch (LoginException ex)
 {
     throw new LoginException(ex.Message);
 }
```

This is how I throw my error

```
if (GetPerson(person.NickName))
    throw new LoginException("Text");
```

Is is my error:

```
public class LoginException:Exception
{
    public LoginException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception details shouldn't be returned to clients. That can result in security leaks. If there's an issue with a username/password or some other condition that can be handled without an exception, then use a custom object to represent the problem and return that with an appropriate HTTP status code. If there's an exception due to some service being down or otherwise some other type of server side issue, then catch the exception, log it, and don't rethrow it. Just return an object that indicates to the client that the server side experienced an error (without saying what it is!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often 500 error - is a backend problem error. It is better to throw your exception in another class (an example, LoginService) and catch it in your controller. Then you must not throw an exception in controller, but send normal response like `return BadRequest(ex.message)`.